# Reactjs setInterval with scroll only trigger once

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have auto scroll function and scroll will start when user click the function as follow.

It is scroll 50px to y axis once when user click play button. But it is only scroll once even thought I have added interval. Interval is working because I saw the "scrolling" console.log is increasing. But scroll is not scrolling again.

May I know why scroll is not move again?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { getTrack, getTrackVariable } from "../../gql/track";
import ChordSheetJS from "chordsheetjs";
import {
  YoutubeIcon,
  FacebookIcon,
  PlayIcon,
  PauseIcon,
} from "../../assets/icons/svg_icons";
import { SettingIcon } from "../../assets/icons/svg_icons";
import paths from "../../routes/paths";
import { FacebookShareButton } from "react-share";
import GoTop from "../../components/go_top";

const TrackPage = () => {
  const intervalId = useRef(null);
  const { trackId } = useParams();
  const [track, setTrack] = useState();
  const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(true);
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getTrack, {
    variables: getTrackVariable(trackId),
  });

  const trackRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && !error) {
     setTrack(data?.track);
   }
 }, [loading, error, data]);


 const getChordSheet = (value) => {
   const parser = new ChordSheetJS.ChordProParser();
   const song = parser.parse(value);
   const formatter = new ChordSheetJS.HtmlTableFormatter();
   const chordSheet = formatter.format(song);
   return chordSheet;
    };

 const handleError = (e) => {
   e.target.onerror = null;
   e.target.src = Monk;
   };

  const handleMenuCollapse = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCollapse(!collapse);
    };

  const handleSpeedUp = () => {
    setSpeed(speed + 1);
   };

  const handleSpeedDown = () => {
    setSpeed(speed - 1);
   };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    setPlay(!play);

     if (play) {
      console.log("stop");
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    } else {
      let delayInMs = 100;
      const onScrollStep = () => {
        document.getElementById("content").scroll(0,50);
        console.log("srolling")
      };
      intervalId.current = setInterval(onScrollStep, delayInMs);
      console.log("play");
       }
        };

  return (
    <>
  <div id="setting">
    {/** the big div */}
    <div
      className={` w-36 h-56  bg-primary absolute top-[calc((100vh-384px)/2)]  ${
        collapse ? "hidden" : "right-0"
      } " bg-primary rounded-b-lg items-center justify-center`}
    >
      <div>
        <div className="items-center justify-center mt-5">
          <div className="flex text-xs items-center justify-center ">
            <span className=" text-sm text-white">Scroll</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex text-xs pt-0 mt-0 items-center justify-center ">
            <button
              className="px-2 btn-sm flex w-20 items-center bg-transparent hover:bg-accent border text-white font-semibold hover:text-white border-white hover:border-transparent rounded "
              onClick={handleScroll}
            >
              {play ? (
                <PauseIcon className="text-white mr-2" />
              ) : (
                <PlayIcon className="text-white mr-2" />
              )}
              {play ? <span>Pause</span> : <span>Play</span>}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="flex text-xs items-center justify-center mt-2">
            <button
              className="w-auto bg-transparent mr-2 hover:bg-accent text-white font-semibold hover:text-white py-1 px-2 border border-white hover:border-transparent rounded"
              onClick={handleSpeedDown}
            >
              -1
            </button>
            <button
              className="w-auto bg-transparent ml-2 hover:bg-accent text-white font-semibold hover:text-white py-1 px-2 border border-white hover:border-transparent rounded"
              onClick={handleSpeedUp}
            >
              +1
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {/** the icon div */}
    <div
      className={`flex w-12 absolute  top-[calc((100vh-384px)/2)] h-12 bg-primary
            ${collapse ? "animate-pulse right-0" : "right-36"}
            cursor-pointer bg-primary rounded-l-lg items-center justify-center`}
      onClick={handleMenuCollapse}
    >
      {/* <div className="w-5 h-5 bg-white rounded-full " /> */}
      <SettingIcon />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="track" ref={trackRef}>
    
    <div className="flex flex-col w-full py-1 my-1 items-center bg-gray-50">
      <div className="relative my-6 mx-auto md:min-w-[60%] max-h-full">
        {track ? (
          <div className="w-full">
            <pre
              className="px-5 textarea"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: getChordSheet(track.lyric),
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
  );
};

export default TrackPage;
```

app.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./components/header";
import SideMenu from "./components/side_menu";
import AppRoutes from "./routes";
import withUser from "./hocs/with_user";
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthProvider, setAccessToken } from "./auth/auth_provider";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import AppContext from "./components/app_context";
import "./i18n";
import "./App.css";


function App(props) {
  const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(isMobile);
  const [sideBarFull] = useState(true);
  const location = useLocation();

  const IsNormalPage = () => {
     const blankPages = ["/login"];

     for (let i = 0; i < blankPages.length; i++) {
      if (location.pathname.startsWith(blankPages[i])) return 
    false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.user) setAccessToken(props.user.t);
  }, []);

  const PageHeader = () => {
    return (
  <div className="h-[72px] w-full flex items-center align-middle justify-center bg-neutral shadow">
    <div className="w-full text-center">
      <Header />
    </div>
  </div>
);
  };


  return (
<AuthProvider user={props.user}>
  <AppContext.Provider
    value={{
      collapse: collapse,
      setCollapse: setCollapse,
    }}
  >
    <div className="relative w-full min-h-screen h-full">
      <div className="flex flex-row min-h-screen">
        <div className="w-auto z-0 ">
          <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
            {IsNormalPage() && <SideMenu showFullMenu={sideBarFull} />}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full max-h-screen flex flex-col z-10">
          {IsNormalPage() && <PageHeader />}
          <div id="content" className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
            <Toaster />
            <AppRoutes />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </AppContext.Provider>
</AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default withUser(App);
```

Comment: where exactly the problem is? could you add the full code snippet including your render method?

Comment: I want to do like in ultimate-guiter. There is AUTOSCROLL button https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/eagles/hotel-california-chords-46190

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are toggling the play state in your component
`setPlay(!play);`
Are you trying to scroll to a specific div or just scroll for 50 px in the direction of y-axis?  there are two approaches, you can use window or Refs.

an example using the refs to scroll to a specific node in the dom

```
const ScrollDemo = () => {
   const myRef = useRef(null)

   const executeScroll = () => { myRef.current.scrollIntoView()}

   return (
      <div> 
         <div ref={myRef}>Element to scroll to</div> 
         <button onClick={executeScroll}> Click to scroll </button> 
      <div/>
   )
}
```

or if you just want to just scroll 50 pixel in the direction of y-axis

```
  const scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0,50);
  };


return (
        <button onClick={scrollToTop}>
          Go down 50 px!
        </button>
);
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieved is that it is lyric page. When user click the play scroll button, page will rolling up until can see the at the end of the screen. So I scroll for 50px just for testing. But my onScrollStep function is calling again and again because of setInterval but document.getElementById("content").scroll(0,50); is only process once. I have edit the full code. It should scroll 50px of y-axis each time calling the onScrollStep by interval. And also want to control the scroll speed by clicking the -1 and +1 button.

Answer (score 0):

window.scrollTo is only working with html body. document.getElementById is only working overflow div.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (play) {
      const onScrollStep = () => {
      var e = document.getElementById("content");
      if (e.scrollHeight - e.scrollTop === e.clientHeight) {
          clearInterval(intervalId.current);
          setPlay(!play);
          return;
    }
    e.scroll(0, e.scrollTop + speed);
  };
  intervalId.current = setInterval(onScrollStep, delayInMs);
} else {
  clearInterval(intervalId.current);
}
},[play, speed])
```